# Why is build number increasing but not the version or runtime version number?

Tags: expo, expo-build

When I run expo build the build number increases correctly but the version and runtime version always stays 1.0.0. I have not added it yet to the app store. I have added a previous build to google play but not the updated one yet. Shouldn't it still increase? What am I doing wrong?

app.json

```json
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "version": "1.0.1",
  }
}
```

eas.json

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.7.0",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
   ...
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```